# need to calculate the average elapsed time for query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to calculate the average time for a column of datatype time(1). However, when I run the following query the average is not correct. It's a little low given the values it is using. Can anyone help?

```
    $statement2 = $dbhandle->prepare(
"SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`actualsplit`))) as average 
FROM workoutmasterv6 
where teamid = ? 
and workoutidv2 = ? 
and actualsplit <> '00:00:00.0' 
group by date 
order by date asc");
```

Here is what i get

```
An Athlete      2018-04-29  00:02:01.9  2018-04-30  00:01:59.1
Another Rower   2018-04-29  00:02:00.4  2018-04-30  00:01:56.2
Average         00:02:00.5000           00:01:57.5000
```

The times for the 29th should average and the times for the 30th should average. As you can see they are a little off.

Comment: is there a fiddle to duplicate?  what is the sample data that causes the issue?

Comment: Here is what I get: An Athlete 2018-04-29 00:02:01.9 2018-04-30 00:01:59.1
Another Rower 2018-04-29 00:02:00.4 2018-04-30 00:01:56.2
Average  00:02:00.5000  00:01:57.5000

Comment: 2 things:

1) Are you averaging between the two different athletes for the specified date or are you averaging the specific athletes times between the two dates?

2) Have you considered floating point numbers?http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: I am averaging between the two athletes on the same date.